# A class with only methods

Tags: c#, object-oriented, class-design

What's the name for a class that has only methods? There are no fields/properties. Just two methods with the ability to parse some file in two ways. I have named the class Parser, but it just doesn't seem right to have a class do only that. Or?

Should it be in a class ?

EDIT:

Dummy Example

```
class Parser
{
     public int parseMethod1(string file)
     {
         //parse & return
     }

     public string[] parseMethod2(string file)
     {
         //parse & return
     }
}
```

How could I write an interface `IParser` which allowed me to have a subclass only implement one of the methods?

Comment: and let me guess, those methods are static. Not every problem is a good fit for OOP, and sometimes a procedural solution is preferable. You could refer to a collection of procedures as a *module*. However, I think that in your case an OOP solution would be preferable – why didn't you write two subclasses that each implement a way of parsing the file, and have `Parser` be an interface? Without more context, all we can do is to take a wild guess.

Comment: `Should it be in a class ?` - it is in a class, isn't it? And where else could it be (in C#)

Comment: Why would you want to call it a special name?

Comment: @amon The two methods I have that parse files, have different return types. How would you do this with an interface? I mean don't you HAVE to implement all methods ? So if I wrote a subclass I would have to implement both parse methods even though I only needed one. Or am I completely confused here?

Comment: @D.Singh How about *generics* (aka. type parameters)? `interface Parser<T> { public T parse(string); }` `class SomeParser implements Parser<int> { public int parse(string file) { ... } }` (sorry, I'm used to Java syntax)

Comment: @amon Could you provide a concise example? Given the edit I just made to the post.

Comment: I've seen these called utility or helper classes

Comment: @amon Ah I see! I haven't used generics much before. That was the thing I was looking for :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An object-oriented design may actually be appropriate here, but both your parse methods belong in separate subclasses. You can use *generics* (type parameters) to achieve this. Something like:

```
interface IParser<T>
{
    public T parse(string);
}

class SomeParser : IParser<int>
{
    public int parse(string file)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class AnotherParser : IParser<string[]>
{
    public string[] parse(string file)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```